# MySQL returns some rows 3 times

Tags: php, mysql

I have this query:

```
SELECT w.windate, w.wintime, w.field, w.htname, w.vtname, w.plateumpire, 
       w.fieldumpire1, w.fieldumpire2, w.fieldumpire3, p.pteamname, p.teamcoach, 
       p.pteamdivision, d.originalid 
    FROM sportsdb_wins AS w, playerteams AS p, sportsdb_divs AS d 
    WHERE p.teamcoach='$coachid' 
        AND p.pteamname IN (w.htname, w.vtname) 
        AND p.forteam='$teamid'
```

and at least one of the rows is returned 3 times! Why? Please help I am a SQL novice.
Using this in PHP...

Comment: joining table will solve the problem. INNER JOIN playerteams   and IINER JOIN sportsdb_divs with the sportsdb_wins table.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [JOIN](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/Visual_SQL_Joins.aspx)'s when you have to join the tables. Your current problem is a so called cartesian product.

[image]

Comment: Still returns the same results! Now the query is `"SELECT w.windate, w.wintime, w.field, w.htname, w.vtname, w.plateumpire, w.fieldumpire1, w.fieldumpire2, w.fieldumpire3, p.pteamname, p.teamcoach FROM playerteams AS p INNER JOIN sportsdb_wins AS w ON p.pteamname IN (w.htname, w.vtname) WHERE p.teamcoach='$coachid' AND p.forteam='$teamid'` but no joy! Got rid of divs

Answer (score 1):

You have no join condition defined for the `sportsdb_divs` table, so you're getting a cross product of those results. This would be more obvious if you used explicit joins (which you should be doing in all of your SQL code).

```
SELECT w.windate, w.wintime, w.field, w.htname, w.vtname, w.plateumpire, 
       w.fieldumpire1, w.fieldumpire2, w.fieldumpire3, p.pteamname, p.teamcoach, 
       p.pteamdivision, d.originalid 
    FROM playerteams AS p
        INNER JOIN sportsdb_wins AS w
            ON p.teamname in (w.htname, w.vtname)
        INNER JOIN sportsdb_divs AS d 
            ON ?????
    WHERE p.teamcoach='$coachid' 
        AND p.forteam='$teamid'
```